# In PHP's str_replace(), what does the double backslash mean?

Tags: php, string, text, replace, str-replace

I want to remove all `\r` `\n` `\r\n` which is pretty easy to so I wrote:

```
str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$text);
```

but I saw this line:

```
str_replace(array("\r","\n","\\r","\\n"),"",$text);
```

and I was wondering what is the double backslash means `\\r` and `\\n`.

Comment: `\n` is _one_ character (newline symbol), `\\n` is _two_ characters: backslash and the letter `n`. Backslash escapes itself.

Comment: see [character escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php). It represents the literal '\' character.

Comment: It means lousy programming, if it's needed to remove such sequences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\` is an escape character, it's used to escape the following character.

In `"\n"`, the backslash escapes `n` and the result will be a **new line** character.

In `"\\n"`, the first backslash escapes the second backslash and the `n` is kept as is, so the result is a string containing **`\n`** (literally).

See the [PHP official documentation > Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

In the context of your question, `str_replace()` will remove new lines (`"\n"` and `"\r"`) and also remove `\n` and `\r` from the string (`"\\n"` and `"\\r"` respectively). There's no reason a text contains the words `\n` and `\r`, so it seems that using `"\\n"` and `"\\r"` has no interest here.

Answer (score 2):

The first backslash escapes the second one, so it matches a literal backslash in `$text`.

I'm not sure why you would want to match that if you just want to remove newlines and carriage returns from the string.

Comment: I guess they want to remove double escaped newlines as well. Why they *have* double escaped newlines is perhaps a question best left unasked.